# Ordering of has_and_belongs_to_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, rails-activerecord

In my rails app I have two models that are related by has_and_belongs_to_many.  This means there is a join table.

Imagine the scenario where I am adding users to a game. If I want to add a user, I do:

```
@game.users << @user
```

Supposing that I want to know in what order I added these users.  I can do this:

```
@game.users.each do....
```

My questions are:

1. Is the ordering if this list guaranteed to read the same way each time?
2. If that's the case, What's a clean way to reorder the users in the game?

Comment: `has_and_belongs_to_many :users, -> { order('users.id ASC') }`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To expand on the bottom of danivo's answer:

If you want to order by the time they are added to this list then I recommend that instead of using a `has_and_belongs_to_many` you actually use a `has_many :through`:

**game.rb**

```
has_many :played_games
has_many :users, :through => :played_games, :order => "played_games.created_at ASC"
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :played_games
has_many :games, :through => :played_games
```

**played_game.rb**

```
belongs_to :game
belongs_to :user
```

Of course, changes pending on the names...

In the *played_games* table if you have a column called `created_at` the second `has_many` in games will order by this field and return the users in the order of which they were added to the game.

Comment: I think this can work for me... to give more context - I don't need to sort by user name, rather I want the server to randomly pick an order so that player positions in the game are decided by it.  So I guess I can put a 'player_index' field in the played_game table, and supply indices at the point I want to decide who moves first....

Answer (score 12):

I'm not certain but I would say that the order is as guaranteed to be the same as your database guarantees the order of the result set without an order by clause.

You can add a `:order => "last_name, first_name asc"` to the `:has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship statement.  This will set a default behavior for the order of the items that comes back.

You can also do `@game.users.find(:all, :order => "last_name, first_name asc")` or create named scopes for common ordering that you will need. [Check out the api for details](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001836)

If knowing the order you added them is really important, you probably want to switch to a `has_many :through` relationship so that the join table has an entity of its own.  Then you will have a `created_on` and `updated_on` timestamp for that relationship managed by rails.

Comment: The SQL standard explicitly says nothing about ordering. It's usually creation order because that's how record get picked up when result sets are being assembled, but that's just a coincidence. A database that's had a lot of updates may have records all over the place. User order if it matters. I've been burned in Rails with #last returning different things for postgres.